# UTF-8 Encoding is not showing special charachters

Tags: python, utf-8

#### Question:

I'm facing an issue with my Python function that reads data from a CSV file and converts it to JSON format. The CSV file contains special Slovenian letters such as "č," "š," "ž," etc. I'm using UTF-8 encoding for both reading and writing the files, which, to my knowledge should support these characters. However, the function doesn't seem to handle these characters the way I intended it to. They appear as Unicode Escape sequences in the output JSON file.

Here is a simplified version of the function:

```py
import csv
import json

def read_rail_nodes(_in_file: str, _out_file: str) -> None:
    json_objects = []
    with open(_in_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(csv_reader)
        for row in csv_reader:
            id, station_name, _, _ = row
            json_objects.append({'id': id, 'station_name': station_name})

    with open(_out_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        json.dump(json_objects, indent=4, fp=file)

    print("\n[rail_nodes.csv] data converted and saved to [", _out_file, "]\n")

read_rail_nodes('rail_nodes.csv', 'rail_nodes.json')
```

**Sample Input:**

```
43002,Laško,46.15453611,15.23225833
```

**Sample Output:**

```json
    {
        "id": "43002",
        "station_name": "La\u0161ko"
    },
```

**Desired Output:**

```
    {
        "id": "43002",
        "station_name": "Laško"
    },
```

I am working in VS Code and I've double-checked my encoding, It is set to UTF-8, and opening the `.josn` file with any other encoding only made it worse.

I have been contemplating a single potential solution, although I am cautious about potential complications that may arise in the future. It occurs to me that employing UTF-8 encoding when reading the .json file could be a viable remedy. However, when it comes to visually presenting the JSON data, I find myself in a bit of a predicament as I am currently unable to devise a suitable approach

Am I missing something in my code, is there something specific I need to do to properly support special Slovenian letters when processing files with UTF-8 encoding, or are my hands tied?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

#### Additional Information:

Python version: 3.11.3 
Operating System: MacOS

Comment: I have searched something. It shows unicode number but once read by Python again it appears as 'š'. 

I tried it inside Python console so I believe it should work as you want it to.

Comment: @JohnyCapo Yeah, I figured that. I'm leaning toward manually replacing the codes with the special letters one by one. The dataset isn't too big, so I reckon it should be doable.

Comment: The JSON standard does not allow raw UTF-8, so pythons library correctly escapes it. All proper programs will read in the string and convert the escape sequences to a single character (Whatever this means).

Comment: Exactly, just as Megalng said.

Comment: If you had UTF-8 in your JSON file, other programs might break and be unable to read in the JSON file (although unlikely, not impossible, for example slightly older python versions (below 3.7 I think?) would not default to UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're facing is not with your code, but with how Python's `json.dump()` function is escaping Unicode characters.

If you want to see the JSON with the actual Unicode characters displayed directly, you can use the `ensure_ascii` parameter of the `json.dump()` function, set it to false and the JSON will be written using the actual Unicode characters instead of escape sequences, for eg:

```
json.dump(json_objects, indent=4, fp=file, ensure_ascii=False)
```